# My JavaScript code to display a mobile menu works on android but not on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

So i have a project in Angular that has a mobile menu, there is one module that has the header and the mobile menu. This code is executed in the Typescript of the module of the header-mobile (module).

I tried to execute the code in the global module of Angular, in Typescript and in to the end of the HTML, but it doesn't work (in IOS). I also verified the css.

This is the link https://portfolio-7f490.web.app/

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const headerBtn = document.querySelector('.header__bars') as HTMLElement;
  const mobileNav = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav') as HTMLElement;
  const mobileLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-nav__link');

  let isMobileNavOpen = false;

  headerBtn?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    isMobileNavOpen =! isMobileNavOpen;
    if(isMobileNavOpen === true){
      mobileNav.style.display = 'flex';
      document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    }else{
      mobileNav.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
    }

    mobileLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        isMobileNavOpen = false;
        mobileNav.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
      })
    });

  });

  const themeToggleBtns = document.querySelectorAll('#theme-toggle');

  // estado
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

  // carga
  theme && document.body.classList.add(theme);

  // handler
  const handleThemeToggle = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode');
    if(document.body.classList.contains('light-mode')){
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light-mode');
    }else{
      localStorage.removeItem('theme');
    }
  }
  //evento
  themeToggleBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handleThemeToggle)
  });

});
```

Comment: I would move that `mobileLinks.forEach` part outside of `headerBtn?.addEventListener`, or you might get multiple listeners added to each mobileLink.